# Image zooming using jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, zooming

I have two images in my folder: one is smaller and one is bigger.

Smaller image is showing on frontend. When I click this smaller image, bigger image will come on another window by using jQuery zoom function.

It is working in HTML but not working with PHP.

Can you please help me out?

jQuery zoom code:

```js
function zoom(photo, title,w,h) 
{
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);

    var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);

    var targetWin = window.open (photo, title, 'titlebar=0, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
}
```

PHP code:

```php
<?php
    echo  "<img src='./smaller/".$a."' onClick=zoom('./bigger/".$a."',400,500); width='100px' height='91px'>";
?>
```

Comment: Its working as it should. There may be some other problem...

Answer (score 0):

**PHP Code**

```
  <?php
     echo  "<img src='./smaller/".$a."' onClick='zoom(\'./bigger/".$a."\',400,500);' width='100px' height='91px'>";
?>
```